# SSRS How do I add a date range to my x-axis on a line graph?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a Line graph and I want the data to show over a range of 60 days back from current date. How do I do this in SSRS?

Comment: Can you show us what you already have and what you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your line chart, you would use your date field as the Category. In the Category properties, you go to the **FILTER** tab and filter your date to be greater than the current date - 60 days.

For the **Expression**, select your date field, change the **Type** from **Text** to **Date**. Set the **Value** to `=TODAY.AddDays(-60)`

For the Chart **Values**, you would use the field with data that you are trying to show. In my example, I was showing the total (SUM) of **Members** for each date (**MOE_DATE**).

[image]

For more info, here's the long-winded MSDN on Charts - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239351(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify the minimum and maximum axis range in axis options. In my example below I set the maximum to the date parameter of the report, and just used a simple datediff formula in the minimum range.

[image: axis options]

[image: minimum axis expression]